# C: What variables are recognized by the compiler?

Tags: c, compilation

Suppose I had the following C code:

```
union foo {
    int x;
    double y;
} k;
char word[] = "Stack Overflow";
int number = 1;

void doStuff(int n) {
    static char c = 'C';
    char *ptr = malloc(n);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int r = 120;
    k.x = 10;
    doStuff(r);
    return 0;
}
```

Which variables are recognized by the compiler? I know that the global variables `k`, `word`, and `number` are, as well as `c` because it is static, but what about the variables within the functions, such as `r` and `*ptr`?

Comment: this isn't syntaxically correct C. you have a string that you assign to a char,  what do you mean by "recognized by the compiler"??

Comment: `double 7;` you cannot use a number as a variable name.

Comment: Oops, I just edited it to be a char array and it looks like I had accidentally hit the '7' instead of the 'y'!

Comment: If you post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem, you won't have that silliness.

Comment: I want to most know the answer to one of @Jean-FrançoisFabre's questions: what do you mean by "recognized by the compiler"?

Comment: @MichaelBurr, I am trying to figure out which variables are "seen" and allocated memory by the compiler during compilation

Comment: `int r` and  `char *ptr` which you ask about, are both local variables so their scope and life is only within the function which defines them. Did the compiler object to them? BTW you have a memory leak because local variables are forgotten at function exit, so you will never be able to `free(ptr)`.

Comment: @lillemap: *No* variables are allocated memory during compilation - that happens at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Storage for objects is allocated at runtime according to the following (incomplete set of) rules:

- If the object is declared at file scope (outside the body of any function) or with the keyword `static`, then storage for the object is guaranteed to be set aside and initialized when the program starts and released when the program exits.
- If the object is declared within a block *without* the `static` keyword, then storage for the object is guaranteed to be set aside when the program enters the object's enclosing scope and released when the program exits that scope.  *In practice*, most compilers that I know of will generate code to allocate all such block-scope variables at function entry.

See §6.2.4 of the [online draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) of the C 2011 standard for a more complete list.

Comment: It might also be of interest to the OP that the 'as-if' rule allows a compiler to avoid actually setting aside memory for a variable when the compiler can determine it's not necessary, such as when the variable can live in a register or when the same block of memory can be used for separate variables because the times when the memory is needed for those variables don't overlap. So in the example code, `doStuff()` might not actually allocate memory for either `c` or `ptr`. Since I'm not sure exactly what the OP is trying to understand, I'm not sure if this is something that he/she cares about.